# Issue while posting to a rest service

Tags: c#, rest

I tried doing this with restsharp, but no luck...  so I'm trying to do a post to a rest webservice.  I was given sample xml as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<request>
<APIClientID>0</APIClientID >
<Version>0</Version>
<APIPassword>password</APIPassword >
<Function>functionName</Function >
<Params>
<UserId>(current-datetime)</UserId >
<page>example.aspx</page>
<application>appName</application>
<function>functionName</function>
</Params>
</request >
</root >
```

the code I'm trying to do the post with is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";

        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXML);

        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        // Write data  
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

However, every time I try to do the post all I get back is the generic get response from the service.  Any help on what I could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

I guess it might help to post the xml that I get back from a get on the service...

```
<Function>TransAPIStats</Function>
<Method>
<post>
<Description>Post api statistics to the DB via the API.</Description>
<Params>
<Client>
<Required>true</Required>
<Description>String</Description>
</Client>
<Page>
<Required>true</Required>
<Description>Integer</Description>
</Page>
<Application>
<Required>true</Required>
<Description>String</Description>
</Application>
<Function>
<Required>true</Required>
<Description>String</Description>
</Function>
</Params>
<Return>
<Result>String</Result>
<Status>String</Status>
<Description>String</Description>
</Return>
</post>
</Method>
```

I tried altering the sample xml that I was given me to match the parameters listed in the api xml, but it still just does the same thing.  I have a feeling that's where my issues is, but it doesn't seem to want to work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";

using (var postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    postStream.Write(requestXML);
}

string responseString = null;
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I made the changes, but its still just returning the get response.  I added some more details to my post, hopefully that will give some more details to help...